# Loopback get a model related with hasMany

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I have one model called `subscription` has a relation of hasMany with another model `category`.

How to fetch the models for a specific subscription.

Note: Not from API-explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is:

- In *common/models/subscription.json*:

  ```
    {
     ...
      "relations": {
          "categories": {
            "type": "hasMany",
            "model": "Category",
            "foreignKey": ""
          }
      }
   }
  ```
- In *common/models/category.json*:

  ```
    {
     ...
      "relations": {
          "subscription": {
            "type": "belongsTo",
            "model": "Subscription",
            "foreignKey": ""
          }
      }
   }
  ```

In REST (ie *from API Explorer*) :

```
GET /Subscriptions?filter[include]=categories
```

In code (ie in a [remote hook](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html#examples) of : *common/models/subscription.js*):

```
Subscription.find({include: 'categories'}, function (err, subscriptions) {
    console.log(subscriptions);
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well explained. F3L1X9.
I want to add somethin here - 
whenever you add a hasMany relation one REST endpoint is created like

`GET /Subscriptions/{id}/categories`

which will give you the categories of the Subscription with the specified ID